# Can a werewolf be killed by any silver weapon or must it be a bullet?

Tags: weapons, werewolves, apotropaism

I typically hear of the silver bullet being the gold standard (so to speak) weapon for killing a werewolf and rarely hear of other weapons successfully doing the job. Even Wikipedia's article on [silver bullets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet) states:

> (it) is often the only weapon that is effective against a werewolf

Is the fact that it is a bullet important in some way?

Is there some mythological context to suggest that the velocity is essential, or would any silver weapon (such as a sword) do the job?

Comment: Could you cite a specific story, instead of just wikipedia? It would help to know what specific story you are talking about (and from what culture: I'm pretty sure werewolfs exist in several different cultures). See my meta post: http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/18/should-we-require-questions-and-answers-to-quote-from-actual-stories

Comment: Concur with Christofian - and this is especially an issue for werewolves, since they have been filtered through the lens of pop culture to a huge degree, making it unclear what actual mythology we're talking about here unless you explicitly state one.

Comment: @Christofian, as of now there is no upvoted answer to your meta post. We can't really consider it a guideline until some form of consensus has been reached. I shall search for a couple of stories that involve it. It is a fairly common trope, though, so had assumed it would be ok.

Comment: Oh I see, that was posted as further explanation of your point, my apologies, I misunderstood.

Comment: In several works a simple touch burns it. In other works it stops his regen. abilities. Or it works as a poison. Swords would work if you could survive a melee fight with a werewolf.